# How to create dynamic Header from API React table

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

How can I create a header for my react table based on the API response?

for example the data I don't want to define columns manually for the table, so how can I create the headers dynamically from the keys of the object

```
let testData = [

{
  "id": "1",

  "name": "test",
  "namespace": "test",
  "description": "test",
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "test2",
  "namespace": "test2",
  "description": "test2",
} ]
```

see answer below

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would like to make the table header static, because you can not control what's returning the endpoint. An approach to this might be this one:

```
const App = () => {
  let testData = [

    {
      "id": "1",
    
      "name": "test",
      "namespace": "test",
      "description": "test",
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "test2",
      "namespace": "test2",
      "description": "test2",
    } ]

  let headers = Object.keys(testData[0]);
  return <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
       {
         headers.map(header => {
          return <th>{header}</th>
        })
        }
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      { 
        testData.map(({id, name, namespace, description}) => {
          return <tr>
            <td>{id}</td>
            <td>{name}</td>
            <td>{namespace}</td>
            <td>{description}</td>
        </tr>
      })
      }
      
    </tbody>
  </table> 
}
```

You could also apply the same logic to avoid inserting the body manually.

Comment: This will not work, I am using react table for handling tables. 
Your solutions work perfectly for normal HTML tables .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution for this

```
let testData = [

{
  "id": "1",

  "name": "test",
  "namespace": "test",
  "description": "test",
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "test2",
  "namespace": "test2",
  "description": "test2",
} ]
```

`//so define the columns`

```
let columns = Object.keys(testData[0]).map(key =>{

return {
//set header and accessor

Header: key,
accessor: key

}

})
```

`//then pass in data and columns variable to table component`

```
  <Table data={tableData} columns={columns} />
```

this is how you create dynamic headers based on data instead of manually defining headers.